# Need slideshow of images when my application is launched in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

How to get the slideshow of images with time interval of 2 seconds. I had referred the below code from stackoverflow but while running iam nt getting any images displayed.. Please tel where iam went wrong...

Xaml:

```
<image Name=myImg Source={Binding bi}/>
```

Code:

```
private DispatcherTimer tmr = new DispatcherTimer();

private List<string> images = new List<string>();

private int imageIndex = 0;

public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);
}

void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    tmr.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
    tmr.Tick += new EventHandler(tmr_Tick);

    LoadImages();

    ShowNextImage();
}

private void LoadImages()
{
    // list the files (includede in the XAP file) here
    images.Add("/images/filename1.jpg");
    images.Add("/images/filename2.jpg");
    images.Add("/images/filename3.jpg");
    images.Add("/images/filename4.jpg");
}

private void ShowNextImage()
{
    Imagesource bi = new BitmapImage(new Uri(images[imageIndex], UriKind.Relative));

    myImg.Source = bi;

    imageIndex = (imageIndex + 1) % images.Count;
}

void tmr_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ShowNextImage();
}

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs      e)
{
    if (!tmr.IsEnabled)
    {
        tmr.Start();
    }

    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
}

protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        tmr.Stop();

        base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
    }
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Change `Name=myImg` to `x:Name="myImg"` and remove the `Source` attribute entirely. Otherwise it looks like it should work.